# How can I render a plain array with mustache.js?

Tags: javascript, html, json, mustache

I am using mustache for template rendering and I face this case:

#### JSON

```
{
  "header": "Colors",
  "colors": ["red", "green", "blue"]
}
```

#### Mustache template

```
<h1>{{header}}</h1>
<ul>
{{#colors}}
    <li>{{???}}</li>
{{/colors}}
</ul>
```

#### HTML

The HTML rendered should be

```
<h1>Colors</h1>
<ul>
    <li>red</li>
    <li>green</li>
    <li>blue</li>
</ul>
```

What should be `{{???}}`? I tried `{{this}}`, `{{colors}}`, `{{color}}` without success so far.

You can use mustache on their [demo](https://mustache.github.io/#demo).

Comment: Their [github page](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/blob/master/README.md#non-empty-lists) says `{{ . }}`. Mustache is definitely a weird templating language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#non-empty-lists):

> When looping over an array of strings, a . can be used to refer to the current item in the list.

View:

```
{
  "musketeers": ["Athos", "Aramis", "Porthos", "D'Artagnan"]
}
```

Template:

```
{{#musketeers}}
* {{.}}
{{/musketeers}}
```

Output:

```
* Athos
* Aramis
* Porthos
* D'Artagnan
```

Comment: Didnt find it in the doc. I bruteforce it x) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is `{{.}}`! In Unix world `.` means current, self. See [Dot (command)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_(command))

#### Mustache template updated

```
<h1>{{header}}</h1>
<ul>
{{#colors}}
    <li>{{.}}</li>
{{/colors}}
</ul>
```